# What are the various solutions to resolving Angular's is not a known element?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-material, webpack-module-federation

My Angular App is throwing 'mat-list' even though I have all the required imported modules. I have already deleted and reinstalled the node_modules folder etc. Are there some specific solutions, loading strategies that helps to ensure that the app doesn't throw this error?

I am specifically using Angular 12 with tsconfig and eslint

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried importing the module inside app.module.ts file?

The import should look like this:

```
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list'
```

I’m guessing you’re using Angular Material.

Comment: this MatListModule should also be mentioned in the `imports: []` section of a module, where the component that is using <mat-list is declared. or maybe in shared module, which is imported everywhere

Comment: I've imported the Angular Material Module into a shared module then import that shared module into the feature module that declares the component that is being used